# Define multiple MQ Server hosts in MQ Client config

Tags: wcf, ibm-mq

Does the MQ client provide the ability to define multiple MQ Server hosts in the client configuration? I have not been able to find anything about it. I wanted to have multiple MQ Servers available with the same queue and if one of them is unavailable, have the client then try to connect to the other server.  I was hoping, like some db instances, you could define numerous hosts and the client driver would route to one that is available.

I know we could add logic that would connect to a different server on connection error, but wanted to use the driver, if possible, to perform this operation.

Using .Net 4.0 WCF / WebSphere MQ 7.1

Any information / comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this link will help you: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27020862

Answer (score 1):

Shashi is the WMQ .Net master so I'll defer to his link in the comments as to the .Net specific answer.

The architecture answer is that you may be complicating this too much.  If the queue in question is advertised to the cluster and the app is sending messages to it, then the app need only connect to any QMgr in the cluster and put to that queue.  It can dynamically create a reply-to queue and use that handle to specify the reply-to address of the request message.  Ideally, service requestor apps are a network hop away from the target queue specifically so that they can utilize WMQ clustering for the purpose you describe.

There is a slightly less ideal scenario in which the client is connected to one of the QMgr instances that hosts an instance of the target queue.  It is possible to configure the queue's `CLWLUSEQ` attribute so that messages are distributed between the local and remote queue instances.

In any of the scenarios where the app is sending request messages, it can be provided with a `CONNAME` containing a comma-separated list of eligible QMgrs to which it can connect.  Modern versions of WMQ let you specify multiple connection points in the `CONNAME` using the `MQCONNX` API.  Both current and older clients can use a `CCDT` file that contains multiple connection definitions and allows the client to switch between them.

If the app is *listening* on the queue for requests, this is a different story.  If that app is transactional, it cannot be configured to fail over to another QMgr.  This is because the XA transaction can only be resolved on the same QMgr instance.  But even setting aside the question of transactions, you usually don't want an app that listens for requests to fail over.  To do so would leave the local instance of the queue un-served and messages would pile up there.  The better answer is to run multiple instances of the server-side app such that each queue instance has at least two app instances serving it.  That way you can take an outage of one of the app instances without having an un-served queue.  Similarly, if a QMgr goes down, messages are automatically routed to the remaining queue instances in the cluster which are served by the other app instances.

There are a number of other architectural reasons which apply to request/reply scenarios and which lead toward a clustered solution.  Other considerations apply to different types of messaging but in general, the answer is that yes, the clients can be configured in several ways to fail over to another queue manager. All of these are based on the QMgr becoming unavailable, not the queue itself.  If the event you are trying to capture is the queue fills or someone PUT(DISABLE) it, the best answer is instrumentation and monitoring, the second best answer is application logic.